# Как отсортировать строки по длине и алфавиту в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Текстовый файл содержит N количество строк.

```
ааа
a
аааб
aa
абаба
вваа
вав
ва
```

Как провести сортировку строк в файле по длине строки и в тоже время алфавиту при помощи регулярного выражения?

Comment: Сортировка по сложному условию с помощью текстового редактора - это похоже на выбор неподходящего инструмента. Лучше использовать любой скриптовый язык.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как провести сортировку строк в файле по длине строки и в тоже время
> алфавиту при помощи регулярного выражения?

сортировка регулярным выражением ? звучит заманчиво, но нет

проще по *старинке*:

```
$ cat FILE |awk "{print length,\$0}" |sort |awk '{print $2}'
a
aa
ва
ааа
вав
аааб
вваа
абаба
```